# Directive in @nestjs/graphql has no effect

Tags: graphql, nestjs, graphql-js

I'm trying to add a Custom Directive with the code first approach following the [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/directives). For now, I use the exact same upper directive. However, the directive seems to have no effect and the code never goes through my custom function.

In the `app.module.ts`:

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
  autoSchemaFile: 'src/schema.gql',
  buildSchemaOptions: {
    dateScalarMode: 'timestamp',
    schemaDirectives: {
      upper: UpperCaseDirective, // no effect
    },
  },
  schemaDirectives: {
    upper: UpperCaseDirective, // no effect
  },
  playground: true,
  introspection: true,
  debug: true,
  // Allow guards and middleware to access req and headers
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    req,
    headers: req.headers,
    databaseConnection: req.databaseConnection,
    updatedAt: req.updatedAt,
  }),
}),
```

Here are the dependencies in my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.3.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.3.2",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.5.5",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.3.2",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.8",
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.14",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.3",
    "apollo-server": "2.15.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "2.15.1",
    "argon2": "^0.24.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.11.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "graphql": "15.3.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nestjs-graphql-dataloader": "^0.1.28",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.14.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.24",
    "typeorm-seeding": "^1.6.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
}
```

Comment: Have you ever found a fix for this?

Comment: It's been 2.5 years so I don't remember what was our use case but there's no trace of it in our code. It may be worth trying with the latest version of nestjs.

Answer (score 0):

per the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/directives#code-first), you aren't configured properly.

The `app.module.ts` should be

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
   transformSchema: schema => userDirectiveTransformer(schema, 'upper'),
   buildSchemaOptions: {
     directives: [
       new GraphQLDirective({
          name: 'upper',
          locations: [DirectiveLocation.FIELD_DEFINITION],
      }),
    ],
  },
},
```